# Elasticsearch client: Unable to get data when * included in index name

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have written the following code in python to get data from my Elastic deployment:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
client = Elasticsearch(<endpoint>,api_key=(<API key ID>,<secret>))
client.get(index="abc-001",id = '--index001')
```

This code works correctly and gives me objectAPIresponse.

But making small change to the code as such:

```
client.get(index="abc-*",id = '--index001')
```

gives me an error:

```
AuthorizationException: AuthorizationException(403, 'security_exception', 'action [indices:data/read/get] is unauthorized for API key id [<id>] of user [<user>], this action is granted by the index privileges [read,all]')
```

I face same issue when using `client.exists(index,id)`

I need to assume that I don't know the full index name and need to know if index "abc-*" does exists in deployment. Even somehow if we can ignore the id and just know if the index is existing, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

as the error said, you don't have required permissions to access the `indexName*`. Probably your previlages has been limited to single index names (e.g abc-001, abc-002, etc) and not to the `abc-*`

So please check your role previlages to see wheter you have such an access or not.
there are two ways to do so:

1. using Kibana management dashboard, the roles section
2. using below query:

```
GET _security/role/<your-role-name>
```

> if you were not granted, ask for it, since there is no other way to
> solve the problem!

### Solution

You need to get such an access, to do so you can use both the Kibana dashboard (simpler way) or the querying approach. ([here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-put-role.html) you can find how to do so)